# dotnet ef migrations using SQL Server when development environment is set to use sqlite

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am on a MAC using .NET Core 2.0

My `program.cs` file is set you the environment set which is development on my machine

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                //.UseStartup<Startup>()
                   .UseStartup("MoviesLibfrary")
                .Build();
```

I have a new class called `StartupDevelopment`:

```
public class StartupDevelopment 
{
        public StartupDevelopment(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddDbContext<MvcTriviaContext>(options =>
                                                    options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MvcTriviaContext")));
        }
}
```

Debugging the application does use the `StartupDevelopment` class.

Using `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate` and `dotnet ef database update` is trying to use SQL Server.

Error I get when running database upgrade

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

Connection string in `appsettings.Development.json`:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MvcTriviaContext": "Data Source=Data\\databasename.db"
  }
```

How do I use `dotnet ef` with sqlite as my development environment is specified to use sqlite?

Comment: take a look at [this](https://medium.com/@yostane/entity-framework-core-and-sqlite-database-migration-using-vs2017-macos-28812c64e7ef)

Comment: That example is no help. The generated code still uses SQL Server APIs.

Comment: so it turns out that I have been mixing my Razor and MVC. I can use SQLite in my Razor app. Should I delete this question since what I was doing was not going to be compatible with the instructions?